# Collect terms with the same denominator

Tags: sorting

I have an expression

$$\frac{A}{x}+\frac{A_2}{x^2}-\frac{D_2}{x}+\frac{C_2}{x^2}++\frac{F_2}{x^3}+\frac{I_2}{x^2y}+\frac{U_2}{y^2x}+\frac{Z_3}{x^2y}+\frac{J_2}{y^2x}+\cdots$$

and I am looking for a Mathematica code that sorts out all terms with the same denominator. So for example

$\frac{1}{x}: A-D_2$

$\frac{1}{x^2}: A_2+C_2$

$\frac{1}{x^3}: F_2$

$\frac{1}{x^2y}: I_2+ Z_3$

$\frac{1}{y^2 x}: U_2+J_2$

In my code I have way more variables than $x$ and $y$, but the example above makes clear what I mean. I had a look into the Collect function, but I cannot apply it to my case...

Here is my code:

```
Expr = A/x + A2/x^2 - D2/x + C2/x^2 + F2/x^3 + I2/(x^2 y) + U2/(
y^2 x) + Z3/(x^2 y) + J2/(y^2 x)
Collect[Expr, x]
```

Unfortunately the collect sorts only in powers of $x$. The output is:

```
F2/x^3 + (A - D2 + J2/y^2 + U2/y^2)/x + (A2 + C2 + I2/y + Z3/y)/x^2
```

what is not what I want (see above)

Comment: Some code to use would help people explore ideas about how to solve your problem, since it would not make them have to type up their own possibly inaccurate examples.

Comment: `Collect[Expr, 1/DeleteDuplicates[Map[Denominator, Apply[List, ExpandAll[Expr]]]]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = A/x + A2/x^2 - D2/x + C2/x^2 + F2/x^3 + I2/(x^2 y) + 
   U2/(y^2 x) + Z3/(x^2 y) + J2/(y^2 x);

expr2 = {1/Denominator[#[[1]]], Total[Numerator /@ #]} & /@ 
 GatherBy[List @@ expr, Denominator]

(* {{1/x^3, F2}, {1/x^2, A2 + C2}, {1/x, A - D2}, {1/(x y^2), 
  J2 + U2}, {1/(x^2 y), I2 + Z3}} *)

expr == Total[Times @@@ expr2] // Simplify

(* True *)

StringForm["``: ``", ##] & @@@
  SortBy[expr2, 1/#[[1]] &] // Column
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In the case of a polynomial in `1/x` and `1/y`, I would replace `x->1/ix` and `y->1/iy` which produces a polynomial in `ix` and `iy`, and then use tools for polynomials.

Example:

```
CoefficientRules[Expr/.{x->1/ix,y->1/iy},{ix,iy}]
(* {{3,0}->F2,
    {2,1}->I2+Z3,
    {2,0}->A2+C2,
    {1,2}->J2+U2,
    {1,0}->A-D2} *)

FromCoefficientRules[%,{1/x,1/y}]
(* F2/x^3
   +(A2+C2)/x^2
   +(A-D2)/x
   +(J2+U2)/(x y^2)
   +(I2+Z3)/(x^2 y) *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
expr = A/x + A2/x^2 - D2/x + C2/x^2 + F2/x^3 + I2/(x^2 y) + 
  U2/(y^2 x) + Z3/(x^2 y) + J2/(y^2 x)
```

**Using `Reap/Sow`**

```
{#[[1, 1]], Total@#[[All, 2]]} & /@ 
  Last@Reap@
    Scan[ Sow[{1/Denominator@#, Numerator@#}, Denominator@#] &, 
     expr] // TableForm
```

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{x^3} & \text{F2} \\
 \frac{1}{x^2} & \text{A2}+\text{C2} \\
 \frac{1}{x} & A-\text{D2} \\
 \frac{1}{x y^2} & \text{J2}+\text{U2} \\
 \frac{1}{x^2 y} & \text{I2}+\text{Z3} \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 3):

```
exprOne = (Select[expr, !FreeQ[#,Power[x]] && FreeQ[#, Power[y]]&]//Collect[#, Power[x]]&)

exprTwo = Select[expr, !FreeQ[#,Power[y]]&]//Collect[#, Power[x], Simplify]&


(exprOne + exprTwo)//TeXForm
```

$$
\frac{A-\text{D2}}{x}+\frac{\text{A2}+\text{C2}}{x^2}+\frac{\text{F2}}{x^3}+\frac{\text{I2}+\text{Z3}}{x^2 y}+\frac{\text{J2}+\text{U2}}{x y^2}
$$

```
Expand[exprOne + exprTwo]==expr

(* True *)
```

To put into a form as desired by OP:

```
{1/Denominator[#], ":", Numerator[#]}&/@List@@(exprOne+exprTwo)//TableForm//TeXForm
```

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{x^3} & : & \text{F2} \\
 \frac{1}{x^2} & : & \text{A2}+\text{C2} \\
 \frac{1}{x} & : & A-\text{D2} \\
 \frac{1}{x y^2} & : & \text{J2}+\text{U2} \\
 \frac{1}{x^2 y} & : & \text{I2}+\text{Z3} \\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2):

```
Expr = A/x + A2/x^2 - D2/x + C2/x^2 + 
F2/x^3 + I2/(x^2 y) + U2/(y^2 x) + 
Z3/(x^2 y) + J2/(y^2 x);


f=Apply[List,Collect[Expr,1/DeleteDuplicates
[Map[Denominator, 
Apply[List,ExpandAll[Expr]]]]]];
Transpose[{1/Denominator[f], Numerator[f]}]
//TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-elegant hack

```
Expr = A/x + A2/x^2 - D2/x + C2/x^2 + F2/x^3 + I2/(x^2 y) + 
U2/(y^2 x) + Z3/(x^2 y) + J2/(y^2 x)

SubsList1 = {1/(x y^2) -> xy2, 1/(x^2 y) -> x2y, 1/x^2 -> x2, 
   1/x^3 -> x3} ;

SubsList2 = {xy2 -> 1/(x y^2), x2y -> 1/(x^2 y), x2 -> 1/x^2, 
   x3 -> 1/x^3} ;

Expr = Expr /. SubsList1

Collect[Expr, {x2y, xy2, x2, x3, x}]  /. SubsList2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
parts = Values[GroupBy[Level[expr, {1}], Denominator, Factor@Total@# &]]
```

[image]

Then, using `Total`:

```
Total@parts
```

[image]

Constructing a rule for presenting the results:

```
rule = Thread[Numerator[parts] -> 1];

Column[StringForm["`2` : `1`", ##] & @@@ 
Transpose@{Numerator /@ parts, parts /. rule}, Spacings -> 1]
```

[image]